# doubleTapListener lib

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, android-view

Столкнулся с проблемой обработки двойного тапа на view.  Может кто нибудь знает библиотеку которая упрощает сию задачу. Или кто может привести пример как повесить OnDoubleTapListener на view? Заранее спасибо))).

Comment: через таймер в клик лиснере или RxJava с TimeInterval оператором

Comment: @Sviat Volkov Похоже на правду. Опубликуете?

Comment: я не могу, у меня лапки. напишите сами себе ответ)

Comment: Хорошо спасибо :)